# Как удалить идущие подряд дубликаты в списке?

Tags: java, list

У меня есть `List<String>` со значениями, например: `["a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d"]`. Из него должно получиться `["a", "b", "d"]`. Причём, если после удаления дубликатов возникли новые, то удалить нужно и их тоже. Например, список `["b", "a", "a", "b"]` должен остаться пустым после обработки.

Мой код не делает то, что нужно

```
static List<String> noDupl(List<String> strings) {
    for (int i = 1; i < strings.size() - 1; i++) {
        if(strings.get(i).equals(strings.get(i + 1))){
            strings.remove(strings.get(i));
            strings.remove(strings.get(i+1));
        }
    }
    return strings;
}
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: 1. цикл начни с 0 2. после удаления, индекс следующего элемента будет i. В связи с этим, после удаления i-=2; if (i == -2) i = -1 (1, т.к. могут идти 3 одинаковые буквы подряд и еще 1 для обработки последовательностей типа baab) 3. в remove достаточно кинуть только индекс

Comment: Вам следует более тщательно описать поведение которое вы хотите получить и дополнительные условия (например сделать это в рамках работы со списком). Иначе легко можно накидать десяток вариантов, как удалить две буквы "а" и чем как, в какой последовательности их заменить, и не ответить на то что вас интересует.

Comment: @Mark плюсую. А то я уже устал править коммент, основываясь на комментариях к другому ответу

Answer (score 0):

```
     for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++){
         if (list.get(i).equals(list.get(i + 1))){ // пара одинаковых записей подряд
             list.remove(i + 1); // тут можно даже написать list.remove(i)
             list.remove(i);     // и удалить еще один элемент
             i = i == 0 ? -1 : i -2 ;             
         }
     }
```

Ищем пару, удаляем, продолжаем поиск с предыдущего элемента (вдруг там новая пара).

Comment: А если список будет ["a", "b", "a"]?

Comment: Тут нет подряд идущей пары. Список останется как есть.

Comment: написано, что, например, список ["b", "a", "a", "b"] должен остаться пустым после обработки. А "b" стоят не подряд.

Comment: пара bb образуется после удаления пары aa, и за счет сдвига индекса на -1 будет обработана таким же образом

Comment: у меня чет даже не заходит в блок if, ввожу строку aabbcc, после работы метода на выходе та же строка и осталась

Comment: А вы как вводите строку? Может у вас получается список, где всего 1 элемент и он и есть ваша строка? А по факту надо же составить список из букв вашей строки

Comment: Не работает на `["a", "b", "b", "a"]`

Comment: Да, действительно, нужно заменить `i--;` на `i = i == 0 ? -1 : i - 2 ;`

Answer (score -1):

```
List<String> sList = new ArrayList<>();
sList.add("2");
sList.add("2");
sList.add("3");
sList.add("4");
sList.add("3");

Set<String> sSet = new HashSet<>(sList);
sList.clear();
sList.addAll(sSet);
```

Удалит все дубликаты!
В консоль: 2 3 4